# What markup can we use in an Evernote action when creating an IFTTT recipe?

Tags: if-this-then-that, evernote

Does anyone know if there is any documentation around the Evernote markup that can be used in the body of an Evernote action for an IFTTT recipe?

I have found the following Evernote dev documentation that shows a fairly robust set of accepted markup here: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php

However, when I create a recipe it appears to be a very limited subset of what is allowed through the Evernote API and I can't for the life of me find any documentation.

Here's the general markup that I know I can use:

- Header tags (h1 -> h6)
- Div
- Span
- Line Breaks (br)
- Ordered Lists
- Horizontal Rule
- Hyperlinks

Does anyone know what markup is accepted and or if documentation is available?